# I want to compare between the height of scrollbar and the document height

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

What I want is, an example when passing the mouse on element in page, **then forced to increase the height of scrollbar, in that case, I want to shows alert box**.

I have used the following code

```
if(document.body.offsetHeight < document.body.scrollHeight ){
    alert('not Equal')
}
```

Also I have used `clientHeight` function Instead of `offsetHeight` function,
But he does not work well except only in chrome and safari browsers.

Update....

Comment: are you tested height instead of offsetHeight?

Comment: `document.body.height` tells me `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can not determine if the page has scrollbars using document.body, use an div container instead, it must have overflow css property and specified height and / or width. After this you can use .offsetHeight and .scrollHeight to dermine if the content is bigger than the size of the container.